# MVC 4 Windows Authentication & Custom Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I've been spending some time trying to grasp exactly the best way to handle authentication/authorization in my app.  I am using windows authentication and I am able to read the users name.

To authorize the user I want to query a database to get their role and create a custom principal for the user with that role.

I believe the what I have below will work, however, I was just curious if there is a better way to query the database only once instead of using a session variable as a check?

The code below is in my Global.asax.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            if (this.Session["Authenticated"] == null)
            {
                using (AppToolsEntities db = new AppToolsEntities())
                {
                    var user = db.ADObjects.Where(x => x.CN == User.Identity.Name.RemoveDomain()).FirstOrDefault();
                    string[] roles = new string[] { user.Title == "EA" ? "Reviewer" : "Admin" };
                    GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                    this.Session["Authenticated"] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Thanks in advance.